# React - why is my component re rendering correctly with PureComponent even though I have nested values?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about Pure.Component. As I understand, if I have a nested state/ not primitive values, React is only doing a shallow compare of the props (with PureComponent), so even if values have changed, React won't re-render my Component because here values won't be compared, only their reference.

I the code below, I do have a nested object. When this.state.person.name changes, my Child component re renders, when it doesn't change it does not re render = which is exactly how PureComponent should work. However, I don't understand why it is working, since it doesn't compare the value of person.name but only reference which is same.

So shouldnt my Child Component be NEVER re rendered, since reference is same ?! Thanks!

also: here is the link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/julianyc/pen/eqNJjE?editors=1010

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       person: {
         name : ""
       }
    }
  }

  changeName = () => {
    let names = ["alice", "mike", "sarah", "josh", "ben", "ally", "lina"];
    let num = Math.round(Math.random() * names.length);
    this.setState({
      person: {
         name: names[num]
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world! </h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeName}>Change my name</button>
        <Child name={this.state.person.name}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    console.log("render of child occured")
      return (
        <div>Child says: {this.props.name}</div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly.   It doesnt compares the state of App. It will compare the props value in Child *(which is string). They change in every button click right ? So that would re-render the Child component.

Comment: ahhh I get it now. if I actually passed the object, not the string, then purecomponent works as expected (never re renders) because it does shallow compare.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compare the state of App component. It will compare the props value in Child *(which is a string). Since that is changing in every button click, Child component will re-render.